# Get direct reports from exchange.. passed variable is empty in exchange query filter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have built a query to retrieve the direct reports, it is working..

```
Get-User -Filter {Manager -eq "CN=k,OU=caone.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR01A003,DC=prod,DC=outlook,DC=com"}|select Name,Manager
```

but when I pass it in a variable, the data I'm getting is something if my variable is `$null`.

```
$m="CN=k,OU=caone.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR01A003,DC=prod,DC=outlook,DC=com"
Get-User -Filter {Manager -eq $m}
```

Comment: according to what i have read, the `-Filter` for the AD cmdlets actually needs to be a STRING. many of the examples show your _scriptblock_ format. that works with very, very simple filters. it fails with anything more than that. ///// the fix is to use a proper filter string. in this case, i think you need `-Filter "Manager -eq '$m'"`. ///// note the inner quotes are singletons while the outer quotes are doubles.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2074130-how-to-list-a-direct-reports-in-powershell